# Hyperlink text value in .resw resources

Tags: localization, resources, windows-phone-8.1

I got problem with localizing my Windows Phone 8.1 application. I would like to create checkbox with text "I accept rules", where "rules" is hiperlink to another view. I've no idea how to bind word "rules" with my .resw file.

```xml
<CheckBox>
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" x:Uid="/RegisterPage/RulesAccept">
     <Hyperlink NavigateUri="" x:Uid="/RegisterPage/RulesAcceptHyperlink"/>
  </TextBlock>
</CheckBox>
```

Now, RulesAccept is "I accept" and "RulesAcceptHyperlink" is "rules" but in my application word "rules" is not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```xml
<TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords">
    <Run x:Uid="RulesAccept"/>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="">
       <Run x:Uid="RulesAcceptHyperlink"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Then in *Resources.resw* file specify which properties should change:

> RulesAccept.Text = "I accept"
>
> RulesAcceptHyperlink.Text = "rules"

You can find more about *Localization* [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx).

Comment: Still dosn't work. I understand how .resw works but i have no idea how to send content to Hyperlink control.

`<TextBlock><Run x:Uid="/RegisterPage/RulesAcceptHyperlink" /></TextBlock>`
This code is working only for TextBlock, for Hyperlink not.

Comment: @bari As I've tried, it seems that when you put *Text* from resource loader, it replaces *Inlines*. One method can be to ommit *Text* in *TextBlock* and define everithing in *Inlines* - see edited answer.