# Reference string resource in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, resx

I am unclear how do I reference a control text property using string resources in Windows Phone 8.1?

For instance I have:

```
<HubSection x:Name="MySection" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}" Header="{StaticResource MyText}">

and 

<AppBarButton Name="MyAppBar" Label="{StaticResource MyText}" ...>
```

and

They both reference MyText which I want to load from resource .resx file.

Comment: You can find some information [here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx), also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27599764/2681948) may help a little.

Comment: [Maybe this will help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965326.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To Refer Any control Property from resources in the XAML, create a `x:Uid` for that control say for a TextBlock, I made a control like :

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="Header" Text="from Resx" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
```

And in the `Resources.resx` define a new Resource with name **Header.Text** and Value as desired say, **My Header Text**. See the screenshot below :
[image]